# Dask Dataframe describe method returning NaN values on quantiles

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have the following dataframe

```
np.random.seed(42)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'score': np.random.poisson(42, 100000)})
```

and created a dask dataframe:

```
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(dataframe, npartitions=10)
```

and run `describe` method on both

```
dataframe.describe(percentiles=[.25, .5, .75, .85, .9]).score.to_frame().T
```

Result is:

```
         count      mean      std   min   25%   50%   75%   85%   90%   max
score  100000.0  42.00748  6.50478  17.0  38.0  42.0  46.0  49.0  50.0  73.0
```

but running the same on dask dataframe

```
dask_df.describe(percentiles=[.25, .5, .75, .85, .9]).score.to_frame().compute().T
```

gets the following result

```
         count      mean      std   min  25%  50%  85%  75%  90%   max
score  100000.0  42.00748  6.50478  17.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  73.0
```

So how come it gets `NaN` values while the pandas dataframe gets the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `quantile`:

```
print (dask_df.quantile(q=[.25, .5, .75, .85, .9]).compute().to_frame().T)
       0.25  0.50  0.75  0.85  0.90
score  38.0  42.0  46.0  49.0  51.0
```

you get the right values and actually if you don't select the column 'score' after doing the `describe`, you get:

```
print (dask_df.describe(percentiles=[.25, .5, .75, .85, .9]).compute())
              score     0
count  100000.00000   NaN
mean       42.00748   NaN
std         6.50478   NaN
min        17.00000   NaN
25%             NaN  38.0
50%             NaN  42.0
85%             NaN  50.0
75%             NaN  46.0
90%             NaN  51.0
max        73.00000   NaN
```

so the values you are looking for are in another column. Here I can't explain why so I can't really answer the question you ask, but at least you see what is going on.

Finally to get the result you look for, then select the column before using `describe`:

```
print (dask_df.score.describe(percentiles=[.25, .5, .75, .85, .9]).compute().to_frame().T)
      count      mean      std   min   25%   50%   85%   75%   90%   max
0  100000.0  42.00748  6.50478  17.0  38.0  42.0  50.0  46.0  51.0  73.0
```

although the `%` are not ordered and the values are not exactly the same

Comment: Yes that is the true about the order of the columns. But thank you. To be honest, I didn't try selecting the column first. But I also don't know why isn't working on the dataframe, and why it is adding an additional column. Also there is a slight difference between the .9 quantile of the pandas dataframe and the dask dataframe :)

Comment: @Apostolos it may be a bug if there is only one column, because if you add another column in `dataframe`, then `describe` in `dask` works like in `pandas`